# Не могу установить Pygame на Windows

Tags: python, pygame, установка

Не могу установить Pygame на Python 3.8. Уже писал функции:

```
pip3 install pygame

pip install pygame

C:\\Users\\[имя пользователя]\\pip3 install pygame
```

Не вышло, пишет ошибку и подчёркивает букву **i** в слове install

Вот ошибка:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install pygame
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Выведи саму  ошибку

Comment: В CMD это надо вводить- pip3 install pygame

Comment: Я там уже вводил

Comment: Покажи вывод, командной строки после ввода этой команды.

Comment: Я уже показал! Вот ошибка:

File "<stdin>", line 1
pip install pygame
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Добавьте pip в переменные среды
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqLN2vKpq7Q
3. Переустановите Python и при установке поставьте галочку в пункте Add pip to path (у меня была такая же проблема и пункт 3 работает 100% - сам проверял).

Помогло?

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно попробую, но тему закрывать не буду, вдруг не сработает)

Comment: если надо добавить `pip` в переменные среды, то нажми `Win` + `R`  и введи `systempropertiesadvanced`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)))